# Почему при обновлении задеплоенного на firebase hosting react приложении появляется страница с ошибкой

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

Всем привет. Я задеплоил свое реакт приложения на firebase hosting, и, вроде, все работает неплохо. Но сейчас я заметил проблему. Если я захожу на сайт по коренному пути, то все подгружается нормально, сам роутинг тоже работает нормально, я могу без проблем перемещаться по сайту. Но вот если я перезагружаю страницу или захожу на сайт, но уже не по коренному пути, то все ломается. Показывается вот такая страничка. Не подскажете, как это исправить?

Если что, можете сами посмотреть: https://houses-inkerri.firebaseapp.com . Просто нужно открыть ссылку, перейти на какую-нибудь из страничек и потом обновить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, даже не знал что это, такая, глобальная проблема) Кстати, если кому-то, вдруг, понадобится этот вопрос, то firebase уже предоставляет вариант автоматической настройки всех путей, записывая их всех в файлик index.html. Для этого нужно просто положительно ответить в соответствующем пункте при настройке firebase init hosting